# C# Form Load method not firing when IsHandleCreated = true

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have a main Form with a button on it that opens up a new Form (`MyForm`) when clicked.

```
 MyForm f = new MyForm();
 f.Method();
 f.Show();
```

If I set `MyForm` to a local variable then the `MyForm_Load()` method does not fire. However if I do something like

```
new MyForm.method();
```

The `MyForm_Load()` method does fire (tested with breakpoints).

I understand that if I create a variable to `MyForm` then the `IsHandleCreated` property is true and this interferes with the `MyForm_Load` being fired. Is there anyway to overcome this problem?

Comment: What does `IsHandleCreated` have to do with the code you displayed?  I have never heard of any interference with this property and the Load event...

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you, f.Method() was firing an exception that was not visible without the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox being ticket, due to how my enterprise handles exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyForm_Load()
```

is Raised when the Form is fully loaded, this means that it must be shown too. Simply Call

```
MyForm.Show();
```

To show it and Raise the Event

Comment: Sorry, I am calling f.Show(), I just forgot to include it in my question, apologies.

Comment: What does f.Method(); do? and have you add the Right Eventhandler added to the Event?

Comment: f.Method was firing an exception that I couldn't see due to my settings/how exceptions are handled at my enterprise. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `f.Method()` is not firing an exception.

(Originally a comment, moved to answer because you said this fixed the issue).

Comment: Sorry, I am calling f.Show(), I just forgot to include it in my question, apologies.